# Why do I get SSL error when I crawl a website?

Tags: python, ssl, certificate

I have the following Python script to crawl the price of an Monitor of the website https://www.notebooksbilliger.de :

```
from lxml import html
import csv, os, json
import requests
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/asus+vz239he"
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
RAW_PRICE = doc.xpath('//div[@id="product_detail_price"]')[0].values()[4]
```

but I get the following error: `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.notebooksbilliger.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /asus+vz239he (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)'))`

Do you know why I get this error ?

Comment: A similar script is working for amazon.de ....

Comment: Probably your (default) *OpenSSL* version is too old.

Comment: @CristiFati but I can access the website from my normal browser. Just doesnt work with the script

Comment: I dont have openssl installed on my Windows 10 PC. U think this could be a problem?

Comment: Please include such info (*Python* version, *OS*) in the question.

Comment: Was able to run your script with *Python 3.6* and *Python 3.7*. Probably I have some required certificates in my cert store, and you don't.

Comment: "self signed certificate in certificate chain" the website use a self signed certificate hence it is not signed by one of the CA you trust hence by default (and for good reasons) the software rejects it. You will need to add this certificate to the list of certificate you trust if you want absolutely to connect to this website. Note that in all generic case, if you do that without first double checking things, you may be as well under some sort of active or passive attack, and being connected to something else that the website you think you are connected to.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not best practice but worked for me: page = `requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)`

Added verfiy=False to the request